# Control a Plotly line color according to its value?

Tags: python, colors, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm creating a dashboard in which I would like to compare the difference of price between two regions directly. If the price of region 1 is higher, y is POSITIVE, if the price of region 2 is higher, y is NEGATIVE.
The problem is that I would like the line and its fill to change color accordingly to its value, so it has a better representation.

I'm using fill='tozeroy'. I would like **y-negative = red** and **y-positive = blue**, for the lines and the fill.

```
def func(est1, est2):
    est1, est2 = 'RIO GRANDE DO SUL', 'SANTA CATARINA' # filter to simulate the callback
    df1 = df[df.ESTADO.isin([est1])]
    df2 = df[df.ESTADO.isin([est2])]
    df_final = pd.DataFrame()
    
    df_estado1 = df1.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df1['DATA'], freq="M"))['VALOR REVENDA (R$/L)'].mean().reset_index()
    df_estado2 = df2.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df2['DATA'], freq="M"))['VALOR REVENDA (R$/L)'].mean().reset_index()

    df_estado1['DATA'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df_estado1['DATA'], freq="M")
    df_estado2['DATA'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df_estado2['DATA'], freq="M")

    df_final['DATA'] = df_estado1['DATA'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
    df_final['VALOR REVENDA (R$/L)'] = df_estado1['VALOR REVENDA (R$/L)']-df_estado2['VALOR REVENDA (R$/L)']
    
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name='Comparação', y=df_final['VALOR REVENDA (R$/L)'], x=df_final['DATA'],
        fill='tozeroy', mode='lines'))

    return fig
```

Just for help porpouses, that's the "df_final" format which is returned:
[df_final DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkoW8.png)

Here's the graph that is being returned from the function: [graph returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb18e.png)

Also, how can I style my fill? Maybe add some gradient etc

Answer (score 0):

I found this Plotly reference library, where I scraped the information I'm answering you with: https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#plotly-express

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species",
                 title="Using The add_trace() method With A Plotly Express Figure")
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[2, 4],
        y=[4, 8],
        mode="lines",
        line=go.scatter.Line(color="gray"),
        showlegend=False)
)
fig.show()
```

Basically, if you put "df_final" in the place of df, and change the axis's data, you'll be good to go.